# Change all properties of an object

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to change all properties of an object to a given value, for example to 0? Will it work with nested objects?

I guess it's a noob question, but i started messing around with js only few days ago.

EDIT:

basically it looks like this:

```
var obj1 = {
  obj11: {
    a11: 1
    b11: 2
    c11: 321
  },

  obj12: {
    a12: 31
    b12: 65
    c12: 8776
  }
}
```

All those values are affected by some other functions. I wanted to make a "reset" function that would set all those values to 0. My expected output is:

```
{
  obj11: {
    a11: 0
    b11: 0
    c11: 0
  },

  obj12: {
    a12: 0
    b12: 0
    c12: 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but you'll have to assign that 0 to each individual property. So a solution will have loops, and for the nesting you will probably want to use recursion.

Comment: _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour]

Comment: "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" - my try for it at this stage is to just type all those properties and make them 0. if it was python, i guess i'd be able to make a loop for it, but as i mentioned, my js is still crap, so the answer to my question was meant to be a building block for my loop understaning in js

Comment: [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will give an array of keys for an object, then you can loop over those keys. Mdn is an excellent resource for javascript api questions. You can use `for (const key of arr) {` to create a for loop, or use arr.forEach() to loop over using a callback.

Comment: Can you an example object and what it would look like converted?

Comment: @bukszpryt can you show the expected output as well to make it clearer (this comment says that you want to change the values, but your question is asking how to change the properties)

Comment: as i stated before, i'm a total noob, so apparently my vocabulary might also be crap. i just thought i'd ask for it to get some good example to adapt and something to build on.

Comment: @bukszpryt I understand that, but I'd expect that you have an idea of what the output you're after should look like, right? Do you want `a11` to be converted to `0` (the property), or do you want the value at `a11` (ie: `1`) to be converted to `0` (the value)

Comment: sorry, my bad. i wanted to change values of all properties to 0. english is not my default language, so i don;t only have to think about right technical vocabulary, but also english.

Comment: @bukszpryt so is your expected result (1) or (2) in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/pLmfho1w/

Comment: i'd like to get second result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj1 = {
    obj11: {
        a11:1,
        b11:2,
        c11:321,
    },
    obj12: {
        a12:31,
        b12:65,
        c12:8776,
    },
};

// Declare a function with a single argument o.
function reset(o) {
  // Loop through all of the properties of the argument object o
  for([key, value] of Object.entries(o)) {
    const t = typeof value;
    switch(t) {
      // If the current property has an object value, handle that recursively.
      case 'object': reset(value); break;
      // If the current property has a numeric value, set the value to 0.
      case 'number': o[key] = 0; break;
      // Otherwise print some status information.
      default: console.log('The property '+key+'is of an unhandled type ('+t+').');
     }
   }
}

reset(obj1);

// Print the result for convenience.
console.log(JSON.stringify({obj1}));
```

Comment: This solution is most understandable for me. It's closest to what i'm used to in python. That is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to take advantage of [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Using its [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) argument, you can specify how each value should be transformed. This method will also recursively traverse your object, allowing you to change all values. As this function converts your object to a string, you'll need to convert it back using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
const obj1 = { obj11: { a11: 1, b11: 2, c11: 321 }, obj12: { a12: 31, b12: 65, c12: 8776 } };

const res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1, (key, value) => Object(value) === value ? value : 0));
console.log(res);
```

The above uses an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which gets passed in a key and a value. This will be called for every key/value in your object. The value that you return from the arrow function is the new resulting value in the new object. In this case, that value is the is `0` when the value isn't an object, otherwise, if it is an object, we just return the original object.

**Note**: If you have an object type that isn't serializable (such as a function) as one of your values, then this method will remove that key-value pair.

---

If your object has a consistent structure and doesn't contain infinitely nested objects, you might find it more straightforward to loop over the keys of your `obj1` (`obj11` and `obj12`) using a [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, and then the keys of the inner objects which you can obtain by using the currently looped on key from your outer loop:

```js
const obj1 = { obj11: { a11: 1, b11: 2, c11: 321 }, obj12: { a12: 31, b12: 65, c12: 8776 } };

const res = {};
for(const key in obj1) {
  res[key] = {};
  for(const innerKey in obj1[key]) {
    res[key][innerKey] = 0;
  }
}
console.log(res);
```

---

Finally, you could use a [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) approach, where you use a function to loop the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) (a `[[key, value], ...]` pair array) of your object, with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert every `value` to a `0`. You can then use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to build your object back together from the entries array. If you encounter an object as one of your values, you can recall this function to apply the same logic to the nested value:

```js
const obj1 = { obj11: { a11: 1, b11: 2, c11: 321 }, obj12: { a12: 31, b12: 65, c12: 8776 } };

const changeVals = (obj, newVal) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(
    ([key, val]) => 
      !Array.isArray(val) && Object(val) === val && typeof val === "object"
        ? [key, changeVals(val, newVal)] 
        : [key, newVal]
    )
  );
console.log(changeVals(obj1, 0));
```